# Reconciliation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Greeting = () => {
    console.log("Greeting is called");
    return <h2> Hello World </h2>;
}

class Counter extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        console.log("Counter is called");
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
        }

        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState( (prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter+1 }));
    }

    render(){
        const { counter } = this.state;
        return (
            <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment {counter}</button>
        )
    }
}

const App = () =>
    <div>
        <Greeting />
        <Counter />
    </div>

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I was reading about React Components, Elements, and Instances from the documentation, it says that reconciliation will start when you call ReactDOM.render() or setState(). So here when the state in the Counter Component changes React must generate the element tree and to do that React will start reconciliation from Top to down and when it asks the Greeting component to return the element tree the Message "Greeting is called" must be printed. So when ever we click the increment button we must see the Message "Greeting is called" in the console, but the Message is printed only once tho we click the increment button many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change a component's state via `setState()`, only *that component's sub-tree* will get updated, not the entire React tree.

Comment: But what what about in react routing, does navigating from one Link to another Link re-render the whole app? Can I ask it in another question?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a different question and it depends on the particular React Router you're using.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the whole tree *within* your `<Counter />` is being re-rendered upon calling setState. And because `<Greeting />` is outside of your Counter, it's not getting re-rendered.

If you want your `<Greeting />` component to re-render, you should place it within the render function of your Counter component.